# Split string by dot lua, yet retain double and triple dots

Tags: design-patterns, lua

I'm trying to split a string by a single dot, yet retain double(and more) dots.

My approach is like this,which works only with double dots:

`local s = "some string.. with several dots, added....more dots.another line inserted.";
for line in s:gsub('%.%.','#&'):gmatch('[^%.]+') do
    print(line:gsub('#&','..'));
end`

Another approach was like this

`print(s:match('([^%.]+[%.]*[^%.]+)'))`

which halts after the next sequence of dots, so it does not suit properly.

How could I accomplish this in a pattern matching?

Comment: `for line in s:gsub("%.%.+", function(d) return ("\0"):rep(#d) end):gmatch"[^.]+" do print(line:gsub("%z", ".")) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  , sure its not regex but gets the job done, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local s = 'some string.. with several dots, added....more dots.another line inserted.'
for line in s:gsub("%f[.]%.%f[^.]", "\0"):gmatch"%Z+" do 
   print(line) 
end
```

Comment: 5mo but remembered to select this as the answer thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
local s = 'some string.. with several dots, added....more dots.another line inserted.'

function split_on_single_dot(s)
  local ans, old_pos = {}, 1
  for pos,dots in (s..(s:sub(-1) == '.' and '' or '.')):gmatch '()(%.+)' do
    if #dots == 1 then
      ans[#ans+1] = s:sub(old_pos,pos-1)
      old_pos = pos+1
    end
  end
  return ipairs(ans)
end

-- test
for i,v in split_on_single_dot(s) do print(i,v) end
```